# Are there any mysql storage engines with row locking, and fulltext?

Tags: mysql, locking, full-text-search

Im using fulltext for searches on my site, but there are a lot of updates being done to the table also, which contains 700,000 records. these updates are usually done via cron, by a script that runs every 10 minutes and commits changes from a temporary table where I simply INSERT all the changes for speed purposes, since updating the live table directly is a lot slower.

The table uses MyISAM, so when there are bursts of update queries being done, it overwhelms the server, and it starts lagging, since it locks the entire table for updates.

Are there any storage engines that both have row-level locking, and support FULLTEXT?

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT DELAYED`, to see if mysql can handle the problem better itself, internally?

Comment: yes, tried that. didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 5.6 it's now possible to have fulltext indexes on tables with InnoDB engine.

Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).